# How can I sort lines in a text file based on one of the comma-separated values?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, text-files, filereader

Each line in my movies.txt file loooks like;

id,title,rating,year,genre (rating is an integer from 1 to 5)

```
1,The Godfather,5,1972,Drama
2,Pulp Fiction,4,1994,Crime
```

I want to list the movies sorted by their rating. I was able to sort the ratings but I don't know how to preserve the connection between ratings and lines and I couldn't sort the lines based on ratings.

```
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("movies.txt"));
String line = null;
int[] ratings = null;
int i;
        
try{
  while((line = b.readLine()) != null)
  {
        String[] data = line.split(",");
        int rating = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);
        
        ratings[i] = rating;
        i++;
          
  }
  b.close();
  Arrays.sort(ratings);
            
 }catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Error");
 }
```

Is there any way I can do this by using arrays or something else, **without creating a class and using a Movie object**?

Comment: Why don't you want to create a `Movie` class?

Comment: I mean, this is Java.  Java really wants you to think in terms of instances of a class.  I don't see a downside to creating a custom object.

Comment: Yeah, there is actually a performance upside, since we don't have to re-parse the rating number every time the sort needs to compare two records.

Comment: I mean, you _can_ put the array into a list and access the values from there, but it's just less readable and more error prone than just creating a Movie object and accessing the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using only data[2], we store the whole result of each line and sort by index[2] (as we need to leave it as string, the comparator is sorting not as Integer but as String)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("movies.txt"));
        String line = null;
        List<String[]> lines = new ArrayList();
        int i;

        try {
            while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data = line.split(",");
                lines.add(data);
            }
            b.close();
            lines.sort(new CustomComparator());
            lines.forEach(o -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(o)));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    public static class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String[]> {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
            return o1[2].compareTo(o2[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort the lines by the 3rd element you should first read the lines, then sort them and write them back (that's what I assume you want to do). A naive approach would be to write a comparator that splits each line, parses the 3rd element to an int and compares the values, e.g. like this:

```
List<String> lines = ... //read, e.g. using Files.readAllLines(pathToFile)

Collections.sort(lines, Comparator.comparing( line -> { 
   String[] elements = lines.split(","); //split
   return Integer.parseInt(elements[2]); //parse and return
}));
```

This, however, is very inefficient so you might try and use a couple of optimizations:

- split the lines into arrays when reading and join them when writing
- sort "integer" strings with a little trick: sort by length and then lexically

Example:

```
List<String[]> splitLines = ... //read and split
Collections.sort(splitLines, 
     Comparator.comparing( (String[] e)-> e[2].length()) //help the compiler with the lambda parameter type, at least in my tests it couldn't infer the type otherwise
               .thenComparing( e -> e[2] ));
splitLines.forEach( elements -> writeToFile(String.join(",", elements));
```

This could even be done in a single stream:

```
Files.lines(pathToFile)
     .map(line -> line.split(",")) //split each line
     .sorted(Comparator.comparing( (String[] e)-> e[2].length()) //sort by length and then by natural order
               .thenComparing( e -> e[2] ))
     .map( elements -> String.join(",", elements) ) //join back to a single string
     .forEach(line -> writeToFile(line)); //write to line
```

This is based on a couple of assumptions:

- all lines have the same format
- no title contains a comma or the split is able to handle escaped values
- lines don't have leading or trailing whitespace
- integers don't have leading zeros

How does the sorting "trick" work?

Basically it first sorts integer strings by order of magnitude. The higher the length the larger the number should be, i.e. "2" is shorter than "10" and thus smaller.

Within the same order of magnitude you'd then sort normally taking the order of digits into account. Thus "100" is smaller than "123" etc.

Final notes:

- It would still be better to actually convert lines into `Movie` elements, especially if you have more complex requirements or data.
- Use a proper CSV parser instead of regex and basic string operations.

Answer (score 0):

Create all lines in the list and sort with stream:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    lines.add("1,The Godfather,5,1972,Drama");
    lines.add("2,Pulp Fiction,4,1994,Crime");
    lines.add("2,Pulp Fiction,33,1994,Crime");
    lines.add("2,Pulp Fiction,1,1994,Crime");
    List<Object> collect = lines.stream().sorted(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return Integer.parseInt(o1.split(",")[2]) - Integer.parseInt(o2.split(",")[2]);
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then put sorted collection to file.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **CSV Parser** to load the data into a `List`, then sort the list.

E.g. if using [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/), you can do it like this:

```java
// Load data into memory
List<CSVRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
try (Reader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("movies.txt"));
        CSVParser parser = CSVFormat.RFC4180.parse(in)) {
    parser.forEach(records::add);
}

// Sort data
records.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(r -> Integer.parseInt(r.get(2))));

// Print result
try (CSVPrinter printer = CSVFormat.RFC4180.printer()) {
    printer.printRecords(records);
}
```

*Output*

```
2,Pulp Fiction,4,1994,Crime
1,The Godfather,5,1972,Drama
```